# get logo to display in email header

Tags: laravel

Im using Laravel 7
Trying to send a mail with the logo in the Header section, but it fails.
I can send it as a attachement and Im seeing the image in the attachment list, but how do I get it in the header.

This way works to send the image along as an attachement.
`return $this->markdown('emails.answered' )->attach($img_url);`

This does not work, or maybe it does, but I can see the immage.
`return $this->markdown('emails.answered', ['url_img'=>$img_url]);`

Here is a Construct to build my mailable

```
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->name   = $data[0]['name'];
        $this->id_no  = $data[0]['id_no'];

        $img_url = env('APP_URL')."img/logo.png";
        $this->logo = $img_url;
    }
```

in my blade I have tried this.

`<img src="{{ $message->embed('img/logo.png') }}">` --> **Undefined variable: message**

And this.
`This is your logo`
`![Some option text][logo]`
`[logo]: {{$img_url}} "Logo"`

But nothing wants to get the image in the message header.

This is the image code in the email.
`<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/tUBy2qlV3Ewx803mJ1QPiZ4vxKrPrRAB8qsInc8TGzKEso9Q93o=s0-d-e1-ft#http://img/logo.png" alt="Some option text" title="Logo2" style="font-family:Avenir,Helvetica,sans-serif;box-sizing:border-box;max-width:100%" class="CToWUd">`

[image]

Comment: I think you can just use regular image tag along with `asset()` helper to load image off of disk just like you would render it in any page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as in you email you are getting `http://img/logo.png"` this string means your `env('APP_URL').` this code is not working so you can try this

```php
public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->name   = $data[0]['name'];
        $this->id_no  = $data[0]['id_no'];
        $this->logo = asset('img/logo.png');
    }
```

then

```php
This is your logo 
![Some option text][logo]
[logo]: {{ $logo }} "Logo"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closer but not yet.

`<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/HPd-TgKbjx_KQ5ljrYPN6NE4WynvYZ612I2wrQ5xDBFdX2F-CdeIH_rNnN-l3lxhtQzfzOg=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:8077/img/logo.png" alt="Some option text" title="Logo" style="font-family:Avenir,Helvetica,sans-serif;box-sizing:border-box;max-width:100%" class="CToWUd">`

But, I suspect the image url should point to an online image??
Is there a way to use an attached image as a logo?
This one points too `http://localhost:8077/img/logo.png`

Comment: `http://localhost:8077/img/logo.png` this is generated in local but in live it will generate live url automatically don't worry

Comment: That is all good, but if I use `http://localhost:8077/img/logo.png` in a new browser window, I see the image. But the email still shows an unreachable image. I have updated my question with the result of this.

Comment: try mailtrap.io for localhost image will show but in gmail it won't show as long as it is in live url

Comment: @morne if it solve your issue consider mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the variable in your function()

```
    $img_url = env('APP_URL')."img/logo.png";

    return $this->markdown('emails.answered',['img_url'=>$img_url]);
```

And then use your `img_url` variable set in the array in your blade file

```
This is your logo 
![Some option text][logo]
[logo]: {{$img_url}} "Logo"
```

or you can use it in blade only if url is `env('APP_URL')."img/logo.png"` like this:

```
This is your logo 
![Some option text][logo]
[logo]: {{ env('APP_URL')."img/logo.png" }} "Logo"
```

Comment: on both instances it fails to display the logo. Its SO frustrating befause it sould be a simple thing.